# How Do I Execute a sudo command in a Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell, passwords, sudo

I am using the LaunchD Task Scheduler app to schedule jobs on my Mac Mini.  I would like to execute the purge command every two hours so I won't have to remember to do this in the terminal.  I have to run this using the sudo command.  I want to do this in a way that protects my password.

I have found a lot of different ways to accomplish this with a lot of debate about the solutions.  I decided for now to run the following script.  From my understanding this should keep the command from being written in .bash_history and in cache files.  Right now the permissions for the folder where I have my scripts (and each script) are set to admins & current user having access.

```
#!/bin/sh
export HISTIGNORE='*sudo -S*'
echo "mypassword" | sudo -S -k purge
```

I have read about a process where I could put a password in a secure file and I guess access the password from that file.  I would like to try that process but I could not find an example of how to do this.  I'm thinking that referencing one secure file with the password may be better than putting the password in each shell script.  I would also like to see the command in .bash_history.

Comment: You can set up sudo to allow a user to run a specific command without a password. This is more secure than hard coding a password to run all commands and then trying to keep people from finding it.

Comment: @thatotherguy, great to know.  I want the safest way to do this and protect my password.  The purge command is the only one I want to run without a password for now.  Please add the solution on how to do that as an answer and I will check it and modify my shell scripts. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safe way to do this is to allow the user to run a specific command without a password.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password/159009) from one of StackOverflow's sister sites.

Comment: Before I begin I just to confirm that there are no differences in the solution from that link other than maybe where the sudo commands are stored between using Linux and Mac.  I found the purge command in /usr/sbin instead of /sbin.

Comment: Right. `sudo` is `sudo`. Obviously you'd replace `/sbin/shutdown` with `/usr/sbin/purge` since you want to allow purge and not shutdown.

Comment: I did a variation of what was on the link you provided by creating purge in folder /etc/sudoers.d.  

'user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/purge'

When I executed sudo purge in the terminal it did not require a password.  I changed my shell to use sudo purge.

Answer (score 0):

You want a script to run, as root, every 2 hours so you do not need to remember?

`sudo crontab -e`

`0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /home/lightbe/swanky_script.sh`

...and then your password is protected.